# Reinstalling GRUB after moving partitions on drive

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, gparted, boot-repair

I was resizing my Linux (Ubuntu) partition from LiveCD (USB) with gparted, and so I had moved EFI partition too. Now my EFI partition name is `dev/sda2`, and file system partition name is `dev/sda3`, they are both on sda device.
Gparted is printing the next info about EFI partition:
[Error message from gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFO2F.jpg)

After this I was trying to reinstall GRUB by this [guide](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/), but the first way makes no effect.

Also I tried the second way from this tutorial using boot-repair, but I get this errors:

- `Please enable a repository containing the [linux-generic] packages in the software sources of unknown Linux distribution (sda3). Then try again.`
- `Please enable a repository containing the [grub-efi] packages in the software sources of unknown Linux distribution (sda3). Then try again.`

The problem is I have no access to sda3 because I can't run my OS without GRUB.

Also I was trying to follow this [guide](https://www.techzim.co.zw/2021/01/how-to-restore-ubuntus-efi-partition-in-ubuntu-20-04/), but after `chroot` command execution error is printed:
 `failed to run command '/bin/bash': no such file or directory`.

I can't resolve any of these problems while trying reinstall GRUB, so I wish you can help me.

Comment: From Ubuntu live installer you can try running dosfsck. `man dosfsck` and `sudo fsck.vfat -t -a /dev/sdXY` # where X is drive and Y is partition. Make sure you have only one ESP and make sure the /etc/fstab in your install has new UUID of your new ESP. And with Boot-Repair make sure Internet is working.